# FirebaseVisionBarcode list is empty on initial frame preview

Tags: android, firebase, android-camera2, firebase-mlkit

I'm following the [quickstart-android](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/samples/apps/mlkit/java/barcodescanning) repo for ML Kit barcode scanning. In my implementation, I am noticing that in the `onSuccess` callback is triggered when I first launch my camera to detect barcodes, which is fine. However, the barcodes list itself is empty when I hold the camera up to valid barcodes. The `onSuccess` callback is called, but the barcode list is empty.

When I background the app, then foreground it, then the barcodes list starts being populated (barcodes.size() is no longer zero).

Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening?

```
final FirebaseVisionImage firebaseImage = 
FirebaseVisionImage.fromMediaImage(image, rotation);

FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions options = new 
FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder().setBarcodeFormats(
        FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_ALL_FORMATS).build();

barcodeDetector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionBarcodeDetector(options)
barcodeDetector.detectInImage(firebaseImage).addOnSuccessListener((barcodes) -> 
{          
    // note that the success callback is called and I do get here
    // but barcode list is empty initially                    
    for (FirebaseVisionBarcode barcode : barcodes)
    {
        // we never get here since barcodes.size() is 0
        // until I background the app, then foreground it
        // after backgrounding, then foregrounding, we start
        // detecting barcodes
    }
    }).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
        //TODO: handle failure
    });
```